# passing a vector pair of integers into some function

Tags: c++, function, runtime-error

**This is the problem statement:**

> Given an array of integers nums, sort the array in increasing order based on the frequency of the values. If multiple values have the same frequency, sort them in decreasing order.
>
> Return the sorted array.

Below is the implementation of my code.

Can anyone help me figure out the way to pass these pair of integers into the second function?

```cpp
class Solution {
    public:
        bool sortByVal(const pair<int,int>&a,const pair<int,int>&b)
        {
            if(a.second==b.second)
                return a.first<b.first;
            return a.second>b.second;
        }
        
        vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>&a) {
            int n=a.size();
            vector<int>res;

            unordered_map<int, int> m;

            vector<pair<int, int> > v;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                m[a[i]]++;      
            }
            copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v));
            sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortByVal);

            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)  
                while(v[i].second--)
                {
                    res.push_back(v[i].first);
                }

            return res;
            
        }
};
```

Here is the link of the problem on leetcode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-array-by-increasing-frequency/

Comment: You need to use `pair<const int, int>` instead. Map keys are `const` values. Also, you should be using `size_t` instead of `int` for your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Make `sortByVal` to be static member function.

If you want to stay with non-static version, you have to wrap this function into callable object passing `this` pointer - required to call a member function for object. Use `bind`, or `bind_front` (since c++20):

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(&Solution::sortByVal,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2));
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind_front(&Solution::sortByVal,this));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9d3YYM)